# Angular Videojs No compatible source was found for this media

Tags: angular, media, video.js

Im making an app for watch tv in my bedroom because there's no anthena cable. Im using videojs7 with angular. I can play many channels like this one :

https://hlsliveamdgl0-lh.akamaihd.net/i/hlsdvrlive_1@60531/master.m3u8

My problem is that there's a lot of channels throwing the same error : "No compatible source was found for this media." like this one:

http://rbtvdiglinear-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/241719/ATfallback/master.m3u8

both seems to be the same but the second dont work and i dont know why. Can somebody guide me to the light?

my code if helps:

```html
<div style="min-height: 100vh;min-height: 100vh;display:flex;align-items: center;">
      <video
        id="player"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin rounded"
        controls muted preload="auto">
        <source src ={{canalSeleccionado}}  />
      </video>
</div>
```

```js
  player: videojs.Player;
  public list;
  public canalSeleccionado = 'https://hlsliveamdgl7-lh.akamaihd.net/i/hlsdvrlive_1@583042/master.m3u8';
  public options = {
      fluid : true,
      aspectRatio : '16:9',
      autoplay : true,
      sources : {
          src : 'https://hlsliveamdgl7-lh.akamaihd.net/i/hlsdvrlive_1@583042/master.m3u8',
          // type : 'application/x-mpegURL',
      },
  };
  
  
  
    ngOnInit() {
    this.player = videojs(document.getElementById('player'), this.options, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('onPlayerReady', this);
    });
  }

  cambiarCanal(link) {
    this.canalSeleccionado = link;
    this.player.src({
      // type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
      src: this.canalSeleccionado
    });
    console.log(this.canalSeleccionado);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```